# NSDate how to get current day's fraction/second for the current time zone

Tags: ios, nsdate, iphone-4, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to get a day fraction for the current day to align a sun across a clock dial. I can calculate the day fraction like this:

```
float dayFraction = (int)seconds%(86400+1)/86400.0;
```

The equation above when converted to radians would continuously animate the sun around the clock

This code calculates where to position the sun

```
CGAffineTransform transformHours = [self calculateLabelRelateivePositionFromCurrentTimeWithOffsetClockwiseInDegrees:((int)[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate])%(86400+1)/86400.0*360 ];
```

The problem is that I need to get the day fraction for the current time zone. The equation below **always uses GMT time**. Is there a way to **easily get timestamp or the current time zone offset to apply to the timestamp** It would be great to have this account for **daylight savings** time too!?

```
((int)[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate])%(86400+1)/86400.0
```

**Update:** 
Thank you for the suggestion, I ended up using the following code:

```
int gmtOffset =  [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
int daylightOffset =  [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] daylightSavingTimeOffset];

int daySecond = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]+gmtOffset+daylightOffset)%
```

(86400+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSInteger secondsFromGMT = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
```